# Auto-resolving conflict with unison

Tags: macos, sync, unison

I've set up a custom automated sync between 2 folders (in OSX) with [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) with the following line:

```
unison folder1 folder2 -batch -debug update+
```

Which worked fine until I encountered:

```
Synchronization complete at 12:01:44  (0 item transferred, 1 skipped, 0 failed)
  skipped: example.txt (contents changed on both sides)
```

I'd like the command to automatically sync the most recent version.  Looking in the options:

```
$ unison -help | grep conflict
 -auto              automatically accept default (nonconflicting) actions
 -copyonconflict    keep copies of conflicting files
 -prefer xxx        choose this replica's version for conflicting changes
```

.. which suggests the only way to resolve is with `-prefer`, but I may be missing something.  Is it possible to specify version by time-stamp?

---

EDIT: All relevant bits of the sync report:

```
[update+]   Unchanged file
[update+] buildUpdateChildren(handleChild): example.txt
[update] buildUpdateRec: /path/to/folder1/example.txt
[update] checkContentsChange: archStamp is inode (3373366) / info.inode (3373748) / times: 1433242394.000000 = 1433242527.000000... false / lengths: 110602 - 110611
[update+]   Double-check possibly updated file
[update]   archive digest = (29c46acff8e661513ec7487bc0069c2b,)   current digest = (cdc82c2519076f9e52486b1c881e179d,)

[update+]   Unchanged file
[update+] buildUpdateChildren(handleChild): example.txt
[update] buildUpdateRec: /path/to/folder2/example.txt
[update] checkContentsChange: archStamp is inode (3373726) / info.inode (3373746) / times: 1433242452.000000 = 1433242515.000000... false / lengths: 110602 - 109400
[update+]   Double-check possibly updated file
[update]   archive digest = (29c46acff8e661513ec7487bc0069c2b,)   current digest = (e12ef45f692808d50989ca4b08d8c27f,)

changed  <-?-> changed    example.txt

Synchronization complete at 12:23:37  (0 item transferred, 1 skipped, 0 failed)
  skipped: example.txt (contents changed on both sides)
```

Comment: I can understand why time stamps are not offered to resolve conflicts: if a trivial change on one system is made after a significant change on the other, you would **not** want to keep the later version.

Comment: Fair point. But you'd think there might be some way of discerning substantive changes such as e.g. changing the number of lines in a file.

Comment: Except that text files are in a minority these days, with media and office files predominating, and these are nearly all binary. In any case a substantial text edit may not change the number of lines in a file, hence the use of "content digests" (probably CRC32-derived), where the least change in the source file will produce a completely unrelated digest. Without keeping a third copy of the directories after synchronisation, it is impossible to determine which changes were minor after both files have been updated.

Comment: Drat and fiddlesticks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've given up on time stamp and settled for prioritising one version by adding the argument

```
-prefer /path/to/folder1
```

which resolves the conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help. As Changes in Version 2.48.4:

Added a "copyonconflict" preference, to make a copy of files that would otherwise be overwritten or deleted in case of conflicting changes. (This makes it possible to automatically resolve conflicts in a fairly safe way when synchronizing continuously, in combination with the "repeat = watch" and "prefer = newer" preferences.